# Bash File existence test is always true

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, quoting, test

I have the following lines of bash script to test whether a file exists:

```
MYAPPPATH=$(find $APPDIR -iname myapp* -print)
if [ -e $MYAPPPATH ]
then
    echo "File exists" 
fi
```

However when file starting with "myapp" does not exist, therefore MYAPPPATH='', the above check succeeds again.
See what happens when using `set -x` and the file does not exist:

```
++ find /path/to/app -iname 'myapp*' -print
+ MYAPPPATH=
+ '[' -e ']'
+ echo 'File exists'
```

What is the reason for this?

What do I need to do in order to make this work as expected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When your variable is empty, your command becomes:

```
[ -e ]
```

In this case, you call `[..]` with one argument `-e`. String `"-e"` is not null, so `test` return true.

This behavior is defined by [POSIX test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05):

> In the following list, $1, $2, $3, and $4 represent the arguments
>   presented to test:
>
> 0 arguments:
>
> Exit false (1).
>
> 1 argument:
>
> Exit true (0) if $1 is not null; otherwise, exit false.
>
> ....

To make it works, you must [double quote your variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters):

```
[ -e "$MYAPPPATH" ]
```

This works because `-e` with an argument that is an empty string is false.

Answer (score 5):

Get used to quoting variables. Always quote them; that prevents misassessments when it is necessary:

```
if [ -e "$MYAPPPATH" ]
```

This would not have happened with the bash-specific compound command:

```
if [[ -e $MYAPPPATH ]]
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `[[...]]` was copied by `bash` from `ksh`. It's also supported by `zsh`. So it's not bash-specific (though it's not standard/POSIX sh syntax so should not be used in `sh` scripts).

Answer (score 2):

There are some other ways:

1. Check variable before (with editions according to comments)

   ```
   if [ -n "$MYAPPPATH" ] && [ -e "$MYAPPPATH" ] ; then ...
   ```
2. Use `locate`* instead of `find`

   ```
   if locate -w "$APPDIR/myapp*" ; then ...
   ```

---

*1 To use `locate` don't forget to update files database by `updatedb`

Comment: `-n "$MYAPPPATH"` is easier to understand.

Comment: `-a/-o` should be avoided. Here, probably `$MYAPPPATH`  starts with `./` or `/`, so it shouldn't be a problem, but that code above fails to work properly with some shells (like `bash`) with `MYAPPPATH='!'` or `MYAPPPATH='('` or `MYAPPPATH='-e'`... use `if [ -n "$MYAPPPATH" ] && [ -e "$MYAPPPATH" ]; then...`