# What's the difference between using quotation with parameters and not using in a shell script

Tags: shell

I am reading the book ***The Linux Command Line*** and in the section 27 it teach me how to write a shell script, and in the **File Expressions** section, it said :

> The script evaluates the file assigned to the constant FILE and displays its results as the
> evaluation is performed. There are two interesting things to note about this script. First,
> notice how the parameter $FILE is quoted within the expressions. This is not required,
> but is a defense against the parameter being empty. If the parameter expansion of $FILE
> were to result in an empty value, it would cause an error (the operators would be interpreted as non-null strings rather than operators).

I don't understand "the operators would be interpreted as non-null strings rather than operators", can anyone give me an example? Thanks.

The original code is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# test-file: Evaluate the status of a file
FILE=~/.bashrc
if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then
    if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE is a regular file."
    fi
    if [ -d "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE is a directory."
    fi
    if [ -r "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE is readable."
    fi
    if [ -w "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE is writable."
    fi
    if [ -x "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE is executable/searchable."
    fi
else
    echo "$FILE does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
exit
```

Comment: See [Bash File existence test is always true](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169020/bash-file-existence-test-is-always-true)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, I understand it. BTW **String Expressions** is the next chapter, the author point it here but don't explain it, it's hard to understand.

Comment: This is just one of the many ways failing to double-quote variable references can [cause weird problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of `$FILE` is the empty string and you don't quote the `$FILE` then your `if [ -e $FILE ]; then` becomes `if [ -e  ]; then`. The rule of the `[` command is that if there is only one value between the `[` and the `]` then this is true if the value is not the empty string, and false if it is the empty string (so `if [ "" ]; then` would take the `else`).

With the quoting, then `if [ -e "$FILE" ]; then` becomes `if [ -e "" ]; then`. This has 2 alues between the `[` and the `]`, so a different rule applies.